# How to load images from api url in flutter?

Tags: asp.net, image, api, url, flutter

Im building a flutter app similar to instagram, i need to load the images of the user's profile picture and posts from the api.

I have already declared a function to retrieve the path of the user profile picture in .net core:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetAsync(string id)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = _dbContext.Users.OfType<ApplicationUser>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest();
        return Ok(user.ProfilePicture.ToString());
    }
```

and this is my api function in flutter to retrieve the path of the image:

```
Future<String> getUsers() async {
final response = await http.get("http://10.0.2.2:8070/api/File/07bb2a17-7cd5-471b-973a-4b77d239b6c3");

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  path=response.body.toString();
  x=new File(path);
 // print(response.body);
  return response.body;
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
  // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
  throw Exception('Failed to load post');
}
}
```

When im trying to load the path received from the wwwroot directory using this technique:

```
 Container(
 height: 100.0,
 width: 100.0,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
 shape: BoxShape.circle,
 image: new FileImage(x),
 fit: BoxFit.cover,
 ), ),
```

im getting the following error :(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

What's the correct way to load user posts and images from api?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is easier when using `Image.network` widget instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flutter_insta](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_insta) plugin and get the profile image URL like this

```
FlutterInsta flutterInsta = new FlutterInsta("coding_boy_");
print("Profile Image : ${flutterInsta.imgurl}");
```